# How do I disable the dialog box I get when my application errors on exit? "Unknown software exception 0xc0020001"

Tags: windows, error-handling, windows-error-reporting

I get an error on my unit test and it hangs my TeamCity continuous integration. How can I make it error headlessly? Fixing the error is a separate issue, please don't tell me that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing crash messages in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708521/preventing-crash-messages-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is very likely to use [`SetErrorMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with - at least - `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX`) to shut up any such error dialogs (see the flags in the MSDN docs) and silently have the process terminated.

Another option is to install your own top-level exception handler. In XP and newer you can use [vectored exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On any system including those newer ones you can use [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Part V, particularly chapter 25, of "Windows via C++" by Richter and Nasarre discusses the topic at great length and detail. The particular topic of WER and top-level exception handlers is also discussed in "Advanced Windows Debugging" (though from a different perspective).

Answer (score 0):

[Regedit configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlhJq.png)

[dr.watson configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzE3L.png)

Do same for both 64-bit and 32-bit regedit dir and dr.watson config. After that, write:

C:\WINDOWS\System32\drwtsn32.exe -i

C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\drwtsn32.exe -i

dr.watson will work as default debugger and will not notify.